# Sending request to reCAPTCHA Enterprise API fails

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

I am trying to create ReCaptcha assessment using their [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/reference/rest) in my backend server.

From reading the documentation, I understand that the request body contains an instance of [*Assesment*](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.assessments#resource:-assessment), but when I try to send a request, I receive the following error:

> TypeError: Object of type Assessment is not JSON serializable

My code:

```py
import requests
from google.cloud import recaptchaenterprise_v1
from google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise_v1 import Assessment

def create_assessment(project_id: str, recaptcha_site_key: str, token: str, recaptcha_action: str, apiKey:str):

    # Create event object
    event = recaptchaenterprise_v1.Event()
    event.site_key = recaptcha_site_key
    event.token = token

    # Create assesment object
    assessment = recaptchaenterprise_v1.Assessment()
    assessment.event = event
    
    # Set project name
    project_name = "projects/"+project_id

    response = requests.post(url="https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com/v1/"+project_name+"/assessments?key="+apiKey, json=assessment)

    return response
```

I tried to convert the `assesment` to JSON using `dumps()`, but I had no success.

I've also tried to write it as "skinny JSON" like so:

```
assessment = {
    'event': {
        'token': token,
        'siteKey': recaptcha_site_key,
        'expectedAction': 'LOGIN'
    }
}
```

Even though I receive status code 200, it indicates that my request is *MALFORMED*, probably because I don't include some `recaptchaenterprise_v1` objects that should be on the `assesment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `CreateAssessmentRequest` to create the request instead, like so:

```py
client = recaptchaenterprise_v1.RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient()
project_name = "projects/"+project_id

# Build the assessment request.
request = recaptchaenterprise_v1.CreateAssessmentRequest()
request.assessment = assessment
request.parent = project_name

response = client.create_assessment(request)
```

You can find a more complete code sample in GCP's **[documentation](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/samples/recaptcha-enterprise-create-assessment#code-sample)**.

Comment: Thanks, I followed GCP documentation and used service account for authentication...
But I now have another issue - I always get 0 score and the error 
"The CreateAssessment call failed because the token was invalid for for the following reasons: InvalidReason.MALFORMED"

I used the write project_id, site_key and token (but not sure what to write on the action variable)

Comment: This means that the token you're using is invalid, or has expired. I can't help you much more giving the information you provided. If you found my answer helpful, please consider marking it as 'Accepted', thank you! :)